# How to display table in following format in simple Html code

Tags: css, html, html-table

I want to display image content in table format using simple Html code. How can I do that ?[image]

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Depending on which aspect of the image you are talking about, this could be quite an interesting question. The rows of dots to the right of the labels, etc. But as the question stands now, it is too broad, sorry.

Comment: displaying image content in html..? be precise do want text recognition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
fieldset legend {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.table-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.table-wrap > tr > td {
  width: 50%;
}

.table-wrap table {
  width: 100%;
}
.table-wrap table .element {
  position: relative;
}
.table-wrap table .element:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;
  
}
.table-wrap table .element .item {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding: 2px;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 2px;
}
.table-wrap table .element .price {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding: 2px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Standard deduction table</legend>
  
  <table class="table-wrap">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="element">
                <span class="item">Single (cannot be claimed)</span><span class="price">$ 8,000</span>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="element">
                <span class="item">Head of household</span><span class="price">$ 11,200</span>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="element">
                <span class="item">Qualifying window</span><span class="price">$ 16,050</span>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="element">
                <span class="item">Married filing seperate returns</span><span class="price">$ 8,000</span>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Can you explain your use of `<fieldset>`, Nick? Where is the set of form fields in your markup that you are grouping together in a fieldset?

Comment: I'm just using this for a simple title without line going in the background. Ofcourse you can accomplish this on another way without fieldset.

Comment: _I'm just using this for a simple title without line going in the background._ Yep. In the politest and most sympathetic way possible, I think you are abusing `<fieldset>` and `<legend>`. This is not what they mean and it's not what they are for.

Comment: I appreciate there are various ways to achieve the effect. One of those ways is not by using `<fieldset>` and `<legend>`. I want to explain this really respectfully, because it's important that you and everyone else can understand it - the default browser rendering of an element is not an inherent property of that element. You are deploying an element because it _looks like_ something... but elements don't look like _anything_.

Answer (score 0):

Here the minimalist code for table in HTML table:

Here some documentation : https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>      
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>      
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution. Hope it can help you

```css
table {
  width: 45%;
  float: left;
}
table:nth-child(2) {
  margin-right: 5%;
}
table:before,
table:after {
  display: table-cell;
  content: ' ';
}
table:after {
  clear: both;
}
table td,
table p,
table span {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
table p {
  margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
  float: left;
}
table span {
  display: block;
  height: 14px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend align="center">Standard deduction table</legend>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><p>Single (cannot be claimed as dependent)</p><span></span></td>
        <td>$ 8,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><p>Single (can be claimed as dependent)</p><span></span></td>
        <td>$ 3,100</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><p>Head on household</p><span></span></td>
        <td>$ 11,200</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><p>Qualifying widow(er)</p><span></span></td>
        <td>$ 16,050</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><p>Married filling jointly</p><span></span></td>
        <td>$ 16,050</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><p>Married filling seperate returns</p><span></span></td>
        <td>$ 8,000</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have above is a set of *name-value* pairs.

Consequently, rather than a table, I think what you have is semantically best marked up as a *definition list* (`<dl>`) - a series of *data titles* (`<dt>`) accompanied by associated *data definitions* (`<dd>`).

**Working Example:**

```css
.standard-deduction-table {
width: 790px;
text-align: center;
}

h2 {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
z-index: 12;
height: 21px;
padding: 0 6px;
line-height: 21px;
font-size: 14px;
font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

dl {
display: block;
position: relative;
top: -37px;
width: 790px;
height: 64px;
padding: 24px 6px 12px;
border: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
}

dl::after {
content: '';
display: block;
clear: both;
}

dt {
position: relative;
float: left;
clear: both;
z-index: 12;
height: 20px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0 2px 0 0;
line-height: 20px;
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

dd {
display: block;
position: relative;
left: 0;
text-align: right;
width: 370px;
height: 20px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
line-height: 20px;
}

dd::after {
content: '';
position: relative;
display: block;
bottom: 5px;
margin-right: 64px;
border-bottom: dotted 1px rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

dt:nth-of-type(n+4) {
position: relative;
top: -60px;
left: 420px;
}

dd:nth-of-type(n+4) {
position: relative;
top: -60px;
left: 420px;
}
```

```html
<div class="standard-deduction-table">
<h2>Standard deduction table</h2>

<dl>
<dt>Single (cannot be claimed as a dependent)</dt>
<dd>&dollar;8,000</dd>
<dt>Single (can be claimed as a dependent)</dt>
<dd>&dollar;3,100</dd>
<dt>Head of Household</dt>
<dd>&dollar;11,200</dd>
<dt>Qualifying widower</dt>
<dd>&dollar;16,050</dd>
<dt>Married filing jointly</dt>
<dd>&dollar;16,050</dd>
<dt>Married filing separate returns</dt>
<dd>&dollar;8000</dd>
</dl>

</div>
```